# get pointer to variable stored in reflect.Value in Golang

Tags: go, pointers, reflection

Probably this is question is very simple, but i've spent some time and was not able to find any good solution(
For example we have the following code:

```
var someValue int = 10
v := reflect.ValueOf(someValue)
var v1 reflect.Value // should refer to &someValue, but with using of the "v" variable only
```

I know that the easiest solution will be ***v1 := reflect.ValueOf(&someValue)*** or using of ***reflect.New()*** function, but unfortunately this will not work in my case.

The "v1" variable should be initialized only with using of the "v" variable.

Comment: If you pass `someValue`, there's no way to get the address `&someValue` from `v`.

Comment: You can't somehow get pointer to a variable from a copy of that variable.

Comment: is there a way to get a pointer to a value stored in reflect.ValueOf(someValue)?

Comment: @sergesheff: technically you could with `unsafe`, but why? The interface contains a copy of the value, so the pointer wouldn't do anything useful.

Comment: @JimB for example i want to convert the int value to float, get a pointer to float value and then assign to **float variable. Just want to avoid the creation of unnecessary  variable with using of reflect.New() function.

Want to do some like this:
***
intVal := 10 // int

floatVal := intVal.Convert(<float32 Type>) // float32
ptrFloatValue := <getting pointer to floatVal> // *float32 - don't know how to do this

var result *float32 // points to nil
reflect.ValueOf(&result).Elem().Set(ptrFloatValue) // &(*float32) = *float32 - simply assign the address of variable
***

Comment: @sergesheff: code in comments is really unreadable, but regardless what you're asking is nonsensical. Everything in Go is assigned and passed by value; `v` contains a copy of `someValue`, it has no relation to `someValue` with which you could find the address of that variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `reflect.ValueOf(someValue)`, ValueOf is passed a copy of someValue. The address of the argument to ValueOf is different from the address of someValue at the call site.

Whatever ValueOf returns cannot possibly know about the address of the original someValue, so what you want to achieve here is impossible.

The best you can do is call [Value.Addr](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Addr), which will return a reflect.Value representing the address of the copy of someValue that was passed to ValueOf:

```
var someValue int = 10
v := reflect.ValueOf(someValue)
v1 := v.Addr() // reflect.Value representing a *int pointing to a copy of someValue
var p1 *int = v1.Interface().(*int) // distinct from &someValue
```

Comment: v1 := v.Addr()  - throws a panic: reflect.Value.Addr of unaddressable value